# Installing phpspec

Tags: php, phpspec

I am sure I miss something obvious. But I have problems install and using phpspec. First of all I don't know if I should use phpspec or phpspec2.

I have tried installing like this:
- PEAR (doesn't work)
- git hub (cloning and it gets downloaded okay)
- composer (Seems I only can get dependencies installed)

I would really appreciate if somebody knows a "phpspec for dummies guide".

Or is it just better to use PHPUnit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen http://phpspec.net for a start? It describes how to install phpspec. PEAR is not listed as an installation method for phpspec2 and the pear channel is down at the moment for phpspec 1.x, as we, the maintainers, are not sure weather there is an existing user base that justifies maintaining it.

So for now, weather you want to use 1.x or 2alpha, you have to install it with composer.

PEAR Channels are down for over a week and I have received 3 requests, counting you.

Answer (score 1):

If you install phpspec with composer it is of course only a dependency, because first of all you want to test your actual application and second everything you install with composer is a dependency to your application.

Phpspec for dummies guide: http://www.phpspec.net/docs/introduction.html#getting-started